# Как сделать две колонки с разными отступами на правой колонке чтобы две колонки были ровные

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container{
    max-width: 1090px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    

.section__items{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.section__item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    height: 48%;
}

.section__text{
color: #242121;
font-family: Roboto Condensed;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 18px;
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}


.section__text-content{
color: #242121;
font-family: Roboto Condensed;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 18px;
letter-spacing: 0.6px;

}

 .text-1{
padding-bottom: 48px;

}

.text-2{
padding-bottom: 79px;

}

.text-3{
padding-bottom: 30px;

}
```

```html
<section class="section__one">
<div class="container">
  <h4 class="section__title"> О  ШКОЛЕ, О СЕРФИНГЕ, О КАНАРАХ <span>/</span> </h4>
  <img src="" alt="">
  
  <div class="section__items">
    <div class="section__item">
    <p class="section__text ">Канарские острова не случайно называют европейскими Гавайями – это идеальное место для поклонников серфинга: стабильный теплый ветер круглый год, песчаные пляжи, километры нетронутых просторов и прозрачное море. А настоящей Меккой для серфингистов становится Фуэртевентура – второй по величине остров архипелага.</p>
    
    <p class="section__text ">Именно здесь лучшее в Испании место, в котором можно пройти обучение серфингу. Кроме того, что зимой и осенью сюда приходят огромные атлантические волны, Фуэртевентура может похвастать и множеством  мелководных спокойных лагун, отлично подходящих для обучения начинающих серфингистов.</p>
  
  <p class="section__text ">Серфинг на Канарских островах доступен круглый год – и волны, и подходящая погода здесь есть всегда. Причем волну, подходящую по уровню, сможет найти и настоящий профи, и новичок. Не случайно считается, что именно это место лучше всего подойдет для обучения здесь возможно без сложностей переходить на новый уровень.</p>
  
  <p class="section__text ">Перечисляя достоинства, нельзя обойти и то, что пляжи Фуэртевентуры самые протяженные на Канарах. В итоге невозможно представить их переполненных туристами. Вы столкнетесь только с теми, кого,как и вас, будет интересовать одна цель – обучение серфингу.</p>
  
  
  </div>

    <div class="section__item">
      <p class="section__text-content text-1">Пока что вы только хотите понять, что такое серфинг, или уже испытали всю прелесть катания на волнах, но желаете поднять свой уровень? Наша <br> школа серфинга сможет предложить обучение для любого уровня <br> подготовки.
      </p>

    <p class="section__text-content text-2 ">Четыре часа увлекательных занятий в день помогут вам уверенно покорять волны, почувствовать себя настоящим серфингистом.
    </p>

    <p class="section__text-content text-3 ">Основные достоинства нашей русской школы – высокое качество преподавания и организации занятий, безопасность (все наши клиенты застрахованы в компании Allianz), отличный инвентарь и экипировка (предоставляется на весь курс обучения), в том числе мягкие безопасные доски для начинающих.</p>


    <p class="section__text-content text-4">Сначала мы определяем уровень катания и физической подготовки и только потом составляем программу подготовки. И можем заверить, что после того, как закончится обучение, вы не только получите массу великолепных ощущений, но и это уровень поднимется на новую ступень.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: скорее всего это ошибка дизайна. Один из вариантов - сделать одинаковый отступы - пример https://jsfiddle.net/gfh5xz7d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужен другой подход в вёрстке. У тебя сейчас две колонки по вертикали, а значит текст в одной колонке никак не связан с текстами в другой. **Решение**: создавать обёртки для двух текстов по горизонтали, пример ниже.

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

p {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores deserunt odit eos. Consequatur reiciendis dicta quam, tempora cum tenetur assumenda itaque aut doloribus, laboriosam dolorum facere fugit soluta adipisci dignissimos illum autem deserunt. Laudantium vero culpa esse soluta dolor id.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores deserunt odit eos. Consequatur reiciendis dicta quam, tempora cum tenetur assumenda itaque aut doloribus.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores deserunt odit eos. Consequatur reiciendis dicta quam, tempora cum tenetur assumenda itaque aut doloribus.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores deserunt odit eos. Consequatur reiciendis dicta quam, tempora cum tenetur assumenda itaque aut doloribus, laboriosam dolorum facere fugit soluta adipisci dignissimos illum autem deserunt. Laudantium vero culpa esse soluta dolor id.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores deserunt odit eos. Consequatur reiciendis dicta quam, tempora cum tenetur assumenda itaque aut doloribus, laboriosam dolorum facere fugit soluta adipisci dignissimos illum autem deserunt. Laudantium vero culpa esse soluta dolor id.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores deserunt odit eos. Consequatur reiciendis dicta quam, tempora cum tenetur assumenda itaque aut doloribus.</p>
    </div>
```